# Display comment form of specific page in sidebar

Tags: sidebar, comment-form

I want to display the comment form of a specific page on a sidebar.

It will look like this roughly.

[image]

---

[image]

---

I tried modifying from comments.php and putting it on sidebar.php.

But nothing shows up. Help please?

```
<?php $aspirasi = get_post(2); ?> 
<?php if ( 'open' == $aspirasi->comment_status ) : ?>
            <div id="respond">
                <h3><?php comment_form_title( __('Post a Comment', 'newtheme'), __('Post a Reply to %s', 'newtheme') ); ?></h3>

                <div class="formcontainer">  

                    <form id="commentform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post">

<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
                        <p id="login"><?php printf(__('<span class="loggedin">Logged in as <a href="%1$s" title="Logged in as %2$s">%2$s</a>.</span> <span class="logout"><a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a></span>', 'newtheme'),
                            get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/profile.php',
                            wp_specialchars($user_identity, true),
                            wp_logout_url(get_permalink()) ) ?></p>

<?php else : ?>

                        <p id="comment-notes"><?php _e('Your email is <em>never</em> published nor shared.', 'newtheme') ?> <?php if ($req) _e('Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span>', 'newtheme') ?></p>

          <div id="form-section-author" class="form-section">
                            <div class="form-label"><label for="author"><?php _e('Name', 'newtheme') ?></label> <?php if ($req) _e('<span class="required">*</span>', 'newtheme') ?></div>
                            <div class="form-input"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author ?>" size="30" maxlength="20" tabindex="3" /></div>
          </div><!-- #form-section-author .form-section -->

          <div id="form-section-email" class="form-section">
                            <div class="form-label"><label for="email"><?php _e('Email', 'newtheme') ?></label> <?php if ($req) _e('<span class="required">*</span>', 'newtheme') ?></div>
                            <div class="form-input"><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="4" /></div>
          </div><!-- #form-section-email .form-section -->

          <div id="form-section-url" class="form-section">
                            <div class="form-label"><label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'newtheme') ?></label></div>
                            <div class="form-input"><input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="5" /></div>
          </div><!-- #form-section-url .form-section -->

<?php endif /* if ( $user_ID ) */ ?>

          <div id="form-section-comment" class="form-section">
                            <div class="form-label"><label for="comment"><?php _e('Comment', 'newtheme') ?></label></div>
                            <div class="form-textarea"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" tabindex="6"></textarea></div>
          </div><!-- #form-section-comment .form-section -->

          <div id="form-allowed-tags" class="form-section">
              <p><span><?php _e('You may use these <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> tags and attributes:', 'newtheme') ?></span> <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></p>
          </div>

<?php do_action('comment_form', $aspirasi->ID); ?>

                        <div class="form-submit"><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Post Comment', 'newtheme') ?>" tabindex="7" /><input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></div>
                     </form><!-- #commentform -->
                </div><!-- .formcontainer -->
            </div><!-- #respond -->
<?php endif /* if ( 'open' == $post->comment_status ) */ ?>
        </div><!-- #comments -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build your own form and don't modify `comments.php` - it's purpose is little bit different and I don't think you should include it inside sidebar.

Just put [`comment_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) function call in your sidebar template. It takes 2 parameters: `args` and `post_id`.

So you can do it like this:

```
$args = array(
    ... // your custom arguments (you can leave it empty
);
comment_form( $args, $post_id );
```

Where should you place this code? Somewhere in your sidebar template. (sidebar.php or something like that, but it depends on your theme).

Comment: It's just a query for further knowledge, why it is discouraging to modify or even to build a new comment form [within methodology]?

Comment: WordPress can change the way it processess comment forms. If you'll build your custom form, then it won't work after such change. On the other hand there is WordPress function to do this, and it will still work. If there is WP function to do something, you always should use it to be as compatible with WP as you can. Otherwise you can cause many problems after WP updates or break some plugins (because your custom form won't use default WP filters).